# Spring Boot fails due to a Hibernate error after migrating to JDK 11

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, java-11

I have just migrated to JDK 11 in order to use the latest Java LTS version. If I change the execution JRE in Eclipse from 10 to 11 (and only then), when I try to run my tests, I get the following exception stacktrace (I removed some parts to facilitate reading).

Please note that everything works as expected if I switch back to jdk-10. Obviously I use Spring boot and Hibernate as my ORM. I have already checked the article in http://in.relation.to/2018/09/13/using-hibernate-orm-with-jdk11/ and tried to resolve these dependencies issue. My pom.xml is also shown here.

Is there a known incompatibility between Spring Boot and/or Hibernate with jdk-11? Perhaps another reference missing in pom.xml?

Edit: As correctly pointed out by @nullpointer, Spring 5.1 supports java 11. However, my question explicitly refers to Spring Boot.

pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in gr.certh.inab.ddiws.Application: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
... 33 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695)
... 48 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123)
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:129)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:300)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
... 52 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:91)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:382)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:519)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:88)
... 69 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible(SecurityActions.java:103)
at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass3(DefineClassHelper.java:151)
at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass2(DefineClassHelper.java:134)
at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass(DefineClassHelper.java:95)
at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:131)
at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:530)
at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:515)
at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass1(ProxyFactory.java:451)
at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:422)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:75)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:156)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:58)
... 74 more
```

Comment: Spring Boot 2.0 isn't officially supporting Java 11 nor does Spring 5.0. It might work but currently no garanties. Spring Boot 2.1 and Spring 5.1 do support Java 11. The same probably applies to other framework versions used by Spring Boot 2.0.

Comment: @M. Deinum: Thank you very much for the information. Do you know when is this expected?

Comment: @nullpointer: Thank you very much for the guidance. However, I would not consider this a duplicate question. I explicitly refer to Spring boot.

Comment: Spring 5.1 is already available (but probably won't work with Boot 2.0) and Spring Boot 2.1 is in the milestone phase expected release end of October. As the error appears to come from hibernate you might want to try and updating the version (boot 2.0 uses 5.2 afaik you might want to try 5.3), as well as move to the most recent Spring Boot 2.0 version which is 2.0.5.

Comment: @nullpointer: this is not a duplicate. The referred answer discusses the minimum version of Spring that is compatible with Java 11, whereas the question here is about a problem that occurs when using Spring Boot combined with Hibernate and Java 11. Both "Spring Boot" and "Hibernate" aren't mentioned at all in the referred answer. Although the referred answer can be part of the solution of the question here, but that isn't obvious, and solutions exists for the answer here that don't apply to the referred anwer.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.0 uses Hibernate 5.2 which uses Javassist 3.22, but you'll need Javassist 3.23 for Java 11. So either swich to Javassist 3.23 manually (the answer of @Nicolai) or to Hibernate 5.3 or Spring 5.1 or Spring Boot 2.1.
For more info, see:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14610
http://in.relation.to/2018/09/13/using-hibernate-orm-with-jdk11/
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1.0-M1-Release-Notes

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I assume the problem is that Hibernate depends on an old version of Javassist. [You should use 3.23.1-GA](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-11-migration-guide/#Update-All-The-Things):

```
<dependency>
    <!-- update Hibernate dependency on Javassist
            to 3.23.1 for Java 11 compatibility -->
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.23.1-GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I have other compatibility issues with Java 11 for now, but your suggestion worked.

Comment: Tank you , you save my day.