# How to specify Java version in Spring/Spring Boot pom.xml?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

What is the correct way of specifying Java 11 as the version to be used in Spring (or Spring Boot) pom.xml file?

I.e., what value do I need to put in the `java.version` property of the pom?

For Java 8 we use `1.8`, just like [the documentation shows](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/#use-maven), for Java 9 it's `1.9`.

I'm not sure if Java 11 would be `1.11` (although it seems unlikely), and I've seen it specified as just `11` when using `maven-compiler-plugin`, however I'm not using the compiler plugin.

e.g.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>11</release>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I've searched around and couldn't find the answer, as pretty much any documentation I've read as well as blog posts related to the Java version only show versions 8 or 9.

So what should I use? `1.11` or just `11`?

I tried both and my web server seems to start correctly and compile correctly (IntelliJ shows `Information:javac 11.0.2 was used to compile java sources`) however I'm not entirely convinced that changing the `java.version` value is doing anything, because I can set it to e.g. `100` and everything works fine.

The only related questions I could find are: [Minimum Spring version compatible with Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427248/minimum-spring-version-compatible-with-java-11), [Spring Boot fails due to a Hibernate error after migrating to JDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52512058/spring-boot-fails-due-to-a-hibernate-error-after-migrating-to-jdk-11?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Spring 4.3.x with OpenJDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52891927/spring-4-3-x-with-openjdk-11), but they don't really shed any light.

Comment: After Java 9 there is no "1.xx" anymore. It's just 9, 10 and 11.

Comment: The configuration you have given is perfect. Using the most recent maven-compiler-plugin and use `<release>11</release>`...

Comment: yes, in works in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.3 (Community Edition) with 
openjdk 11.0.18 2023-01-17 - OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.18+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04.1), i just specifed java version for plugin  in pom, and bug fixed.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

The correct way is to use the followings values in `<java.version>` for different Java versions:

- Java 8  : 1.8 or 8
- Java 9  : 9
- Java 10 : 10
- Java 11 : 11
- Java 12 : 12
- .....
- .....
- Java 17 : 17
- Java 18 : 18
- Java 19 : 19

So for Java 11 , it should be:

```
<properties>
   <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
```

> However I'm not sure if Java 11 would be "1.11" (seems unlikely), and
> I've seen it specified as just "11" when using maven-compiler-plugin,
> however I'm not using the compiler plugin.

Actually , at the end it still uses `maven-compiler-plugin` to compile. Springboot just configures a `<java.version>` property such that by changing this value , you are implicitly changing `maven-compiler-plugin` 's `<source/>` and `<target/>` to the same value as what specified in the `<java.version>` :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>11</source>  <!-- same as <java.version> -->
        <target>11</target>    <!-- same as <java.version> -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

---

**Detailed Answer:**

Seem like you want details to convince you.

It is because every spring boot project will extend the parent pom `spring-boot-starter-parent` which [defines](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/b4e890c3be6d35c3473fc5ed67b056ead277285f/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-parent/pom.xml#L18) `<java.version>` as follows:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

From the maven-compiler-plugin [docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#release), `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` are the [user property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391502/whats-the-meaning-of-user-property-of-maven-plugin-parameter) for the `<source>` and `<target>` config parameters. Due to the behaviour of the user property, setting these two properties to `11` means to set the following :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>11</source>   <!-- maven.compiler.source  -->
        <target>11</target> <!-- maven.compiler.target -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

From the `maven-compiler-plugin` [docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#release) again, `<source>` and `<target>` are the `-source` and `-target` argument for the Java compiler (`javac`). Then, from [javac](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/tools/javac.html#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9) docs, we can see that these two arguments are allowed to have the following values:

> - 1.6 : No language changes were introduced in Java SE 6. However, encoding errors in source files are now reported as errors instead of
>   warnings as was done in earlier releases of Java Platform, Standard Edition.
> - 6   : Synonym for 1.6.
> - 1.7 : The compiler accepts code with features introduced in Java SE 7.
> - 7   : Synonym for 1.7.
> - 1.8 : The compiler accepts code with features introduced in Java SE 8.
> - 8   : Synonym for 1.8.
> - 9   : The compiler accepts code with features introduced in Java SE 9.
> - 10  : The compiler accepts code with features introduced in Java SE 10.
> - 11  : The compiler accepts code with features introduced in Java SE 11.
> - 12  : The compiler accepts code with features introduced in Java SE 12.

Hence, `<java.version>` should be set to `11` for Java 11.

Comment: Aha. Nice explanation! This makes everything much clearer. Thanks.

Comment: Consider some projects if not most, in big systems, use spring-boot bom importing instead of extending it's parent. And bom import does not import properties nor plugin versions

Comment: I have java.version in my pom, set to 1.8, but still when I run mvn spring-boot:Run, it says "Starting MyApplication using Java 11.0.15 ...". That's the version my JAVA_HOME points to. Shouldn't the java.version property take precedence over that?

Comment: Nice ! that's clear

Answer (score 10):

If any one looking to specifying Java 11 as the version to be used in Spring (or Spring Boot) in a **gradle** project, then use either sourceCompatibility = '11' or sourceCompatibility = '1.11' in your build.gradle file

```
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'au.com.ranuka'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = '11'
//or 
sourceCompatibility = '1.11'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

}
```

Comment: As this is the top result in Google search, much appreciated

Comment: `sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11`, It works.

Answer (score 7):

I am adding it as an answer so it can be helpful to more people:

Since Java 9 the versions are specified as `9`, `10`, `11`, and so on, instead of `1.8`, `1.7`, etc. Some further reading [here](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/223).

The way you are specifying the JDK version with `<release>11</release>` is correct. It was introduced with `maven-compiler-plugin 3.6` and is equivalent as the old way, as below:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>11</source> -- Using JDK 11 to compile
      <target>11</target> -- Using JDK 11 as target
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

[This](https://mincong-h.github.io/2018/08/29/maven-compiler-plugin-understanding/) post can be helpful on using `maven-compiler-plugin` with JDK 11.

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to mention the maven-compiler-plugin in your POM file,
if you only want to specify the compiler version.
Instead, add these properties to your pom file

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

**Edit:** My bad,
it looks like the version number properties have changed starting with the 3.6 release of the maven-compiler-plugin.
The example above is fine for java 8 and lower.
For java 9,
add this property:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>9</maven.compiler.release>
</properties>
```

Check out the accepted answer to this question: [Specifying java version in maven - differences between properties and compiler plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882080/specifying-java-version-in-maven-differences-between-properties-and-compiler-p)

Comment: First this is simply wrong cause there does not exist a JDK version `1.11` furthermore starting with JDK9+ there is an option `--release` for the compiler which is supported by maven-compiler-plugin via `<release>11</release>`...

Answer (score 0):

Gradle API provides an `enum` for `JavaVersion`.
We can user these constant to define `sourceCompatibility`.

eg.
`sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11`

Below are the few constants

```
VERSION_1_8 - Java8
VERSION_1_9 - Java9
VERSION_1_10- Java10
VERSION_11 - Java11
VERSION_12 - Java12
VERSION_13 - Java13
```